# 2D array of objects returns null

Tags: java, arrays

Code creating object array and toString method.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class TicTacToeBoard extends BoardClass{

    private int turns;

    private XOClass[][] a;

    public TicTacToeBoard(int rows,int cols){
        super(rows,cols);
        XOClass[][]a = new XOClass[rows][cols];
        turns = 0;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return (Arrays.deepToString(a));
    }
}
```

Object Class

---

```
public class XOClass{
    private String name;
    private static int turn=0; 

    public XOClass(){
        if (turn==0){
            this.name = "-";
        }
        if (turn==1){
            this.name = "X";
        }

        else{
            this.name = "O";

        }
    }
```

---

Demo Class

```
public class play {
   public static void main(String[] args){
       TicTacToeBoard tac = new TicTacToeBoard(3,3);
       System.out.println(tac);

    }
}
```

---

when calling class play it returns null as there is nothing in the array what am I doing wrong with my code.

Comment: You're not indenting it properly. Maybe you should fix that first.

Comment: After that change `XOClass[][]a = new XOClass[rows][cols];` in your constructor to `a = new XOClass[rows][cols];` because you want to assign to a member variable, not declare a new local variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

`XOClass[][]a = new XOClass[rows][cols];`

1. You initialize new XOClass its only in the method and when the method end it is distrusting.
   change that to

   `a = new XOClass[rows][cols];`
2. This means you have created a two-dimensional array, with 'rows' rows. In the first row there are 'cols' columns.
   and all rows are null.
   Now you should create rows like :

`a[0] = new XOClass[cols];`

And then

```
    a[0][0]=new XOClass();
```